# How to interpret the `path` attribute in `ElementDefinition`

Tags: hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I'm working on generating FHIR client code and am currently working on generating code for extensions.

I have trouble understanding paths in `ElementDefinition` that contain more than one `.` like for example

```
"path": "Extension.extension.id",
```

from `http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/qicore-adverseevent-cause`

or

```
"path": "Extension.extension.extension.id",
```

from `http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/valueset-history`

How should such paths be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hierarchy in FHIR models is represented using the dot notation.  So Extension.extension.id corresponds to Extension/extension/id from an xpath perspective (or Extension.extension.id from a JSON object navigation perspective).  Every time you see a new period in the path, you're nesting one level deeper.

Comment: Thanks. It still don't get it though. What does one level deeper mean in this concrete examples. Where does it actually point to? Is this the `id` property of an extension of an extension of a resource where this extension is added to? I assumed elements are direct properties of the resource where they are added.

Comment: <extension>
  <extension>
    <id value="foo"/>
  </extension>
</extension>

Does that help?  Elements are direct properties of their parent - it's possible to have complex properties that have sub-properties (and sub-sub properties and sub-sub-sub properties . . .)

Comment: I'm still struggling a bit but I think I start to understand. Thanks a lot for your support!